# How to take input from one csv file and count the words in another file in perl

Tags: perl

I am very new to perl. I want to take string from first column of one csv file and want to check the frequency of this word in another file and want to print the output in third file. Here is my code -

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

$inputfile = 'Input.txt';
$outputfile = 'Out.csv';
$file = 'File.csv';

open(INPUT, "<$inputfile") or die "Could not read from $inputfile, program halting.";
open(OUTPUT, ">$outputfile") or die "Could not open $outputfile, program halting.";
open(FILE, "<$file") or die "Could not read from $file, program halting";

@temp;
@token;
$count;

#skip first line of approved file
if(<FILE>)
{
    (@temp) = split (/\,/);
}
    $count = 0;
    while(<FILE>)
    {
        @temp = split (/\,/); 
        print "First Column - @temp[0], ";
        print "Count - @temp[1], ";
        print "Priority - @temp[3], ";
 $count = 0;
    while(<INPUT>)
    {
        #read the fields in the current record into an array
        @words = split(/\s+/);
        foreach $word (@words)
        {
            $temp1 = @temp[0];
            if($word == $temp1)
            {
                $count++;
            }
        }
}
    print "$temp1 - Count - $count \n ";
    print OUTPUT "$temp1,$count,@temp[3]";
    print OUTPUT "\n";
}   

close INPUT;
close OUTPUT;
close FILE;

print "Done, please check the output file.\n";
```

Somebody please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost thing is always

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

You have misunderstood getting values from arrays as scalar. To fetch a scalar value from array use the following:

```
        @temp = split (/\,/);                 #this is array
        print "First Column - $temp[0], ";    #temp[[0] is scalar value of array
        print "Count - $temp[1], ";            #temp[[1] is scalar value of array
        print "Priority - $temp[3], ";         #temp[[2] is scalar value of array
```

and here

```
foreach $word (@words)
        {
            $temp1 = $temp[0];       #this should be scalar.
            if($word == $temp1)
            {
                $count++;
            }
        }
```

Wherever you are using `@temp[0],@temp[1]`.. is wrong usage it should be `$temp[0],$temp[1],$temo[2]`....

Comment: OK..Thanks.. One more query is - How to compare substring let say $word = 12345 and $temp[1] = 1234 then how to compare

Comment: You are comparing in the right way use chomp to truncate new line when reading a file so that your compare will work.

Comment: @User312 did that help?

Comment: @User312: Please don't extend your question after you have posted it. Additional questions require a new post.